# Would data in vertex buffer change after translation?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

If I load an X file and store vertex data in vertex buffer.  Then, Do translation on object, Would it change data in vertex buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. You store the translation in a matrix right? So in the vertex shader you transform the vertex position by the matrix to calculate the vertex position in world space but it doesnt affect the vertex buffer

Comment: Well, I'm not using vertex shader yet.  How can I get the vertex data then?

Answer (score 2):

No.

(I'd certainly hope not. That would rather defeat the object of the scene graph.)